# Algorithm to embed invisible roubust watermarking for images

Tags: image, algorithm, watermark, invisible, robust

I'm doing a project on invisible robust watermarking for image security. 
I have to develop algorithms to accomplish following tasks.

Construct watermark that cannot be totally removed from an image. Also i have to come up with an algorithm that provides ownership authenticity.

What algorithms that can be used to accomplish these tasks and also to embed invisible watermark to an image? Would be more helpful if you can suggest any samples/tutorials or useful websites on this regard.

Comment: There are (possibly) many ways to achieve what you want. If you have a specific concept in mind but have trouble implementing it, revise your question to provide more information. Suggesting tutorials is considered off-topic. Have you searched the literature to give you an idea of how things are done?

Answer (score 1):

You can search for `Steganography tools`, there are some different algorithm to hide data inside an image with encryption.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography_tools

http://lifehacker.com/230915/geek-to-live--hide-data-in-files-with-easy-steganography-tools